# Algorithm for smallest number in array larger than threshold

Tags: algorithms, integers

We define the problem SmallestAbove as follows:

> Given an array $A$ of $n$ integers and a value $v$, compute the smallest value in $A$ that is strictly greater than $v$. Return $\infty$ if no such value exists.

(Here $\infty$ is just a very large integer constant.)

You may assume that $A$ has at least one value ($n \geq 1$) and that $v$ and all integers in $A$ are smaller than $\infty$.

1. Describe an algorithm for SmallestAbove that runs in $O(n)$ time. You do
   not need to prove its correctness.
2. Analyze the running time of your algorithm.
3. Now assume that $A$ is sorted. Provide an $O(\log n)$-time algorithm for SmallestAbove. You do not have to prove correctness nor analyze its running time.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this exercise? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm completely new to this topic and I don't even know where to  start...

Comment: If you don't know where to start then you'll have a hard time in the remainder of class.

Comment: I'm aware of that

Answer (score 1):

When we say that an algorithm is O(n), it means that if we have an algorithm that operates on n elements, our algorithms will 'touch' or 'visit', in the worst case, n elements (This is a loose definition of big-O, but it will do for our example, if you don't understand Big-O see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)).

So think about the sort of code that would be required for a problem like this. For starters, we're probably going to need a `for` loop that hits every elements (Based on the question, it says we're looking for an O(n) algorithm, so our loop would go from 1 to *n*).

Outside this loop we initialize our value "smallest value" variable to be MAX_INT. Then in our for loop, we have a simple `if` statement that does the following: If ***A***[i] (The current value in the array we're looking at) is greater than *v*, and less then our "smallest value", then set "smallest value" to be equal to ***A***[i].

As for the run time of this algorithm, the time complexity would be: *n*.

This is because every time we run this algorithm, we must visit every element once.

For question 3. Think about how we can optimize this algorithm now that we know it's sorted. If its sorted' we can use this to visit less elements.

In terms of 'O(logn)', this can sometimes be confusing with the 'log' as to what it means. An example of a 'logn' sorting algorithm would be searching through a dictionary. Assume we have an 1000 page dictionary and I want to find the word 'Zoo'. First i split the dictionary in have and go to page 500, then i see words with the letter 'M' so i know i need to go further into the dictionary, so i split the 2nd half of the dictionary in half again and reach page 750. I see the words start with the letter Q and R, so i know that i need to do it again. So i reach page 875 and i keep repeating until i reach Zoo. If I used a 'n' time complexity algorithm, i would have had to visit every page till i found the word. As you can see, logn is much faster.

Use this example to help you come up with a O(logn) algorithm. See if you can modify out 1st algorithm now that we know the list is sorted.